# TFLite model overflows on GPU, ok on CPU. What are the differences internally?

Tags: gpu, precision, tensorflow-lite

On Android, I have a model that runs fine on CPU, but overflows when switching to GPU delegate ('Infinity' in the results). If I rescale the input, I can eliminate the overflow, so it seems an issue of different internal range/precision between CPU and GPU. I was under the impression that both CPU and GPU use by default 32-bit float, so the results should be identical. Does anyone know the internals of TFLite enough to provide some insight?

Comment: Did you set any options when creating the GPU delegate? By default, the Java API's default option is to allow precision loss for faster execution, which will use FP16. See: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/gpu/GpuDelegate.java#L54-L60

Comment: @yyoon, yep, that was it: I was initializing the GpuDelegate without options, and so it was using FP16. Passing options with .setPrecisionLossAllowed(false) fixed the overflow, although processing times increase by ~25-30%, as can be expected.
I don't see how to mark your comment as the correct answer, maybe you have to repost it as an answer.

Comment: Glad it helped! Expanded my previous comment to make it a full answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding floating point precision, the TFLite GPU delegate on Android can run in two modes, which you can choose with the following method in the `Options` class. (copied from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/gpu/GpuDelegate.java#L54-L60))

```java
    /**
     * Sets whether precision loss is allowed.
     *
     * @param precisionLossAllowed When `true` (default), the GPU may quantify tensors, downcast
     *     values, process in FP16. When `false`, computations are carried out in 32-bit floating
     *     point.
     */
    public Options setPrecisionLossAllowed(boolean precisionLossAllowed) {
      this.precisionLossAllowed = precisionLossAllowed;
      return this;
    }
```

Since the default value for this `precisionLossAllowed` option is `true`, your model will run in FP16 mode when using GPU by default. If you want to force running in FP32 mode as in CPU, you should explicitly set this option to `false` when creating the delegate.

```java
GpuDelegate.Options gpuOptions = new GpuDelegate.Options();
gpuOptions.setPrecisionLossAllowed(false);
GpuDelegate gpuDelegate = new GpuDelegate(gpuOptions);

Interpreter.Options interpreterOptions = new Interpreter.Options();
interpreterOptions.addDelegate(gpuDelegate);
Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(tflite_model_file, interpreterOptions);
```

This should give you the same result as in CPU mode, but result in slower execution compared to FP16 mode.

Comment: What if I want 16bit precision? Then how can I avoid NaN?

Comment: How to use it in ML Model Binding?